# I keep getting error 404 on angular client side when trying to reach my api endpoint using identity server 4 for auth

Tags: c#, identityserver4, angular9

Am working on a project using angular 9 as my client side, .net core 3.1 for API, and Identity server 4 for Authentication and authorization. On the client-side level, I can sign in using oidc for authentication and retrieving access tokens using implicit flow grand type. But whenever I try accessing the API endpoint after all necessary configurations without the authorization attributes on my controller I can access the data via the API endpoint, but whenever I add the authorization attribute on the controller I get a 404 HTTP error. What could possibly have gone wrong?
Below is the snapshot of my code implementations and errors:

[image: result when authorization attributes are removed from the controller header].

[image: result when Authorization attribute is added to the API controller]

[image: error result continuation]

[image: error returned in detail]

[image: returned header]

[image: client configuration in Identity 4 server level]

[image: configuration contd]

[image: API configuration for the API]

[image: API call on the angular client side level]

[image: Signin redirect call back]

[image: The Authenticated Route Guard]

[image: User manager configuration]

[image: The http interceptor]

[image: The Authentication service]

[image: Auth service contd]

[image: Auth service contd]

[image: Auth contd]

[image: Auth contd]

[image: Auth contd]

[image: App Module Root Route]

[image: App module.ts]

[image: app module]

[image: Dashboard]

[image: FGTBILLS MODULe]

[image: api service to call the api endpoint]

[image: component the calls the gbnbondtbills service]

Comment: Can you try to decode your access_token using https://jwt.io/ and send the snapshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through some research i found ou that I failed to add identity server default authentication scheme and default challenge scheme on the authentication pipeline on the API startup.cs level.

[image]